# Python Flask not returning cookie / ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, cookies, flask, return

I am still struggling to pass a string in Python to another function.

I am trying to follow the example given here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_cookies.htm

I've tried to implement this into my code but I am now getting the following Traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Which would mean that I am not returning anything, but I can't really see where I'm going wrong and I have to admit I'm quite lost here.

My full code looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import os
from six.moves import cPickle
from model import Model
from six import text_type
import flask 
from flask import jsonify, render_template, request, make_response

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test')
def tester():
    return "This is a test"

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                           formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument('--save_dir', type=str, default='save',
                            help='model directory to store checkpointed models')
        parser.add_argument('-n', type=int, default=500,
                            help='number of characters to sample')
        parser.add_argument('--prime', type=text_type, default=u' ',
                            help='prime text')
        parser.add_argument('--sample', type=int, default=1,
                            help='0 to use max at each timestep, 1 to sample at '
                                 'each timestep, 2 to sample on spaces')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        resp = make_response(render_template('sample.html'))
        resp.set_cookie('args', args)

        return resp


@app.route('/sampler', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def sample():
    args = request.cookies.get('args')
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'chars_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        chars, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, training=False)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.save_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                text = model.sample(sess, chars, vocab, args.n, args.prime,
                                   args.sample).encode('utf-8')
                resp = make_response(render_template('text.html'))
                resp.set_cookie('verse', text)
                return resp


@app.route('/text')
def printer():    
    verse = request.cookies.get('verse')
    return verse


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

before I had tried to just send a cookie from my sample function to the printer function but it returned the same error.

My code before:

```
def sample(args):
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'chars_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        chars, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, training=False)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.save_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            text = model.sample(sess, chars, vocab, args.n, args.prime,
                               args.sample).encode('utf-8')
            resp = make_response(render_template('text.html'))
            resp.set_cookie('verse', text)
            return resp


@app.route('/text')
def printer():    
    verse = request.cookies.get('verse')
    return verse
```

Comment: Instead of just the error message, please post the complete traceback. Also, when does this error happen - to what endpoint and what kind of request you are making? Thanks.

Comment: Just edited the full Traceback. It happens when I try to open http://127.0.0.1:5000/text. I get an Internal Server Error and the Traceback above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `verse` cookie value is not present the value of the `verse` variable would become `None`. Which means that your `text` view would return `None`, which `Flask` does not like and understands as "View function did not return a response".

You may need to handle this case properly - for instance, simply returning an empty string would fix the problem (of course, this is only a sample easy fix to demonstrate the difference):

```
@app.route('/text')
def printer():    
    return request.cookies.get('verse', '')
```

Also, not all the code paths in the `sample()` view return a valid response - make sure to address it as well (for instance, making a `GET` request to the `sample()` view would result into the same "View function did not return a response" error).

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, you will need to return a value outside the request parameter check scope:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
       ....#statements follow            
       args = parser.parse_args()

       resp = make_response(render_template('sample.html'))
       resp.set_cookie('args', args)

       return resp
  return render_template('home.html') #need to return something here
```